# Use the browser cookie in fetch in a WebExtension

Tags: cookies, firefox-addon-webextensions

I’m currently porting an addon from the jetpack to the WebExtension API. I need to continuously update a browser action (toolbar button) with data (e.g. set its badge text).

For this, I would like to do a request from a [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts) in my extension to an API of the page, which is accessible when the user is logged in (i.e. a cookie is set). What I did so far:

1. I gave myself [host permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions), which is mentioned to be necessary for request from content scripts.

   However, [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) are for injecting JS into pages the user visits.
2. I created a background script that uses `fetch` to do a request to the API.

However, when queried from the background script, the API tells me that nobody is logged in, while I can access it with the browser flawlessly.

This is the relevant part of the `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://subdomain.domain.com/*"
  ]
}
```

How can I have a continuously running background script that can use the user’s cookie to access this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has stricter cors restrictions for cookies. I solved this by doing the api call from a content-script injected on the page with the same domain. That api call generated an auth token that was used for api calls from the background page, and enabling cors on backend for requests containing token in auth header.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I’m not updating that extension anymore, so I can’t check your answer, but it sounds like it makes sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to supply the `credentials` option in the arguments to `fetch()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Comment: This did not solve my problem, although I included the option in my fetch requests. I’m using Firefox 67.0 (64-bit). The website keeps redirecting my request to the sign-in page.

Comment: Also doesn't work here for me, Firefox 70, Linux 64